# shallow copy struct got weird result on Xcode

Tags: c, free

The code here is a typical example for shallow copy, it ought to got the warning when running, but on my Xcode, it's running well and result is

> hi,hi
> hi,hi

why?

The code:

```
struct pc
{
    char *p;
};

int main()
{
    struct pc pc1;
    pc1.p = malloc(100);
    strcpy(pc1.p, "hi");
    struct pc pc2 = pc1; // shallow copy
    printf("%s,%s\n", pc1.p, pc2.p);
    free(pc1.p);
    printf("%s,%s", pc1.p, pc2.p);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing memory after you've `free()`d it invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You should **not** be using the `printf()` with the `free()`d memory after you call

```
 free(pc1.p);
```

Comment: "Undefined behaviour" means anything can happen, including everything working fine in development and crashing and destroying user's data when the product is shipped.

Comment: @gnasher729 Thanks for the elaboration. :-)